# Not able to link Crypto++ library in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I was able to set up the Crypto++ library in Xcode using the instructions on https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_(Xcode)

[Snapshot of the built library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFOeD.jpg)

However, I am not able to figure out a way to integrate this library into another C++ project. I am not able to find the option to add this library under Target Dependencies/Linked Libraries.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

after some research, I did somehow manage to integrate the library into a C++ project just yesterday. 
What might have helped:-

- Setting the library & header search paths.
- Dragging the static library to the command line Project & localizing
  the library.
- I also changed the Architectures to Universal x86_64
  & Valid Architectures to x86_64 of the Target file under Build
  Settings. This finally did the trick for me.